# How to repaint a widget in QT designer

Tags: qt, qt-designer

I am just beginning to learn some programming with QT, and would like to start with the designer portion of QT Creator, before diving into the .cpp, and .h files.  I would like to do simple tasks like change the color of a box based on a condition, or perform some arithmetic.  But everything I read describes how to the change the code, not do it in the UI editor.  Even the QT Designer manual gives no demonstration of how to create a simple calculator in Designer.  They only show the code (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-using-a-ui-file.html).  I've loaded the project from the links at the bottom of this page: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdesigner-calculatorform-example.html, but I'm still stumped as to how it does the arithmetic from looking at the UI editor.  I don't see any signals/slots indication an addition on the numbers in the spin boxes.  Nor, do I see anything in the properties of the Output QLabel that makes it the sum of Input1 and Input2.

And just to add another level to this simple example, how could I change the color of the output box if a condition is met? Let's just say if the output is larger than 10, make the box blue.  I see the palette in the Properties box, but how do I make it conditional, staying within the Designer portion of the Creator application?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're searching for a way to execute simple code/actions directly from within qt-designer, without using any code behind.

**That's not possible**, if you use qt-designer and .ui files.
You can connect slots to signals directly from the designer, but you have to implement those slots in your *.cpp file.

If you want to mix the UI design with your application logic take a look at [QML](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-index.html).

Comment: Ok, that makes sense based on all the documentation/videos/forums I've been reading.  But I've also been seeing that the QT framework is being described as something person with no programming experience can work with, because the programming can be done in the UI editor.  If what I'm asking is not possible, why is there even a stand-alone Designer?  I should think the QT Designer would be able to edit QT applications and widgets.

Comment: Designing UI's can be done without writing a single line of code - I guess we agree on that. But adding interactions is not much harder. Try rightclicking on a element in the designer and pick `Go to slot...` from the context menu. You'll be taken to the code-behind where you are able to access the ui like this `ui->label1->setText("hello world")`.

Comment: Ok.  I'll stop being scared of c++ and just learn it.  Thanks for the lead on QML, as well.

Comment: I am still really confused by how the designer portion works with the rest of QTCreator.  I've set up a few connections from pre-defined slots, and they work just fine.  But I don't see them in my .h or .cpp files.  More annoying though, is I'd like to program a custom slot.  I want to use the signals already being generated by stuff in my .ui, and not have to re-program them from scratch.  What am I missing here? The [example] (https://forum.qt.io/topic/800/solved-how-to-see-custom-slot-in-signal-slot-editor/12) here is not working for me.

Comment: And I'm not sure it is true that I want to "execute simple code/actions directly from within qt-designer, without using any code behind."  Isn't that what the signal/slot editor and action editor help do?

Comment: Since you're having a lot of basic questions regarding signals/slots, I suggest you go to the `#qt` channel on [freenode](http://webchat.freenode.net/). It's a bit easier there, than writing comments back and forth here on stackoverflow.